# Are SQL Server stored procedures backed up by default?

Tags: sql-server, backup, stored-procedures, restore

We have two servers running SQL Server 2019 (15.0.x).

When we do a full database backup (by right-clicking the data base, then Tasks, then Backup), does that include backing up the all items under `Programmability` which would then be restored to the other server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When we do a full database backup (by right-clicking the data base, then Tasks, then Backup), does that include backing up the all items under Programmability which would then be restored to the other server?

Yes, a Full Database Backup will include *every* object that exists in that database, as of the moment in time it [finishes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd822915(v=msdn.10)) backing up, as the name implies. Further information can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/full-database-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) which also confirm this:

> A full database backup backs up the whole database. This includes part of the transaction log so that the full database can be recovered after a full database backup is restored. Full database backups represent the database at the time the backup finished.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.

It's way easier to test than to ask question.